# npm ERR! version not found: i@0.3.2 error

Tags: node.js

Please help. I am having a NPM app which when I downloaded locally and trying to do a "npm install" is throwing me the - "npm ERR! version not found: i@0.3.2" error.

```
C:\Users\xyaz\Desktop\MS\MSWeb\WebContent>npm install
npm WARN package.json msportal@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT No description
npm WARN package.json msportal@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT No repository field.
npm WARN package.json msportal@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT No README data
npm WARN package.json msportal@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT No license field.
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v0.12.4
npm ERR! npm  v2.10.1

npm ERR! version not found: i@0.3.2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\xyaz\Desktop\MS\MSWeb\WebContent\npm-debug.log
```

I tried googling and was able to find this solution

https://github.com/pksunkara/inflect/issues/11

but I am not sure how to apply that solution to my problem. 
I mean, I dont see a reference to "i" anywhere in my package.json or I am not able to recognize something that is very obviously present.

Here is my package.json file

```
{
  "author": "QSD",
  "name": "msportal",
  "homepage": "http://www.cqst.com",
  "version": "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT",
  "buildversion": "0.1",
  "distdirroot": "release",
  "distdirextension": "src/content",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 0.8.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "fs-extra": "^0.16.3",
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-cli": "^0.1.13",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "~0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-compress": "~0.9.1",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "~0.4.0",
    "grunt-contrib-connect": "~0.8.0",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "~0.4.0",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-htmlmin": "~0.2.0",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.10.0",
    "grunt-contrib-less": "~0.11.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.6.1",
    "grunt-execute": "~0.2.1",
    "grunt-html2js": "~0.2.7",
    "grunt-include-source": "~0.3.5",
    "grunt-text-replace": "~0.3.11",
    "http-server": "^0.6.1",
    "json-proxy": "~0.1.2",
    "livereloadx": "^0.3.2",
    "load-grunt-tasks": "^1.0.0",
    "time-grunt": "^1.0.0",
    "underscore": "~1.6.0",
    "webserver": "~1.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "prestart": "npm install",
    "start": "http-server -a localhost -p 8000 -c-1"
  }
}
```

I tried doing "npm install -g npm". But, that doesnt help either.
Any inputs on how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i@0.3.2 got unpublished, so anything depending on it will need to be upgraded to use i@0.3.3, which was published almost immediately after 0.3.2 got unpublished.

`npm ls i`

will show you the path to it (and show you that it's MISSING), as well as what depends on it

Update: After editing the package.json to use

```
"json-proxy":"*"
```

you should no longer get this error.

If you're curious the dependency chain looks like this.  json-proxy depends on

```
 optimist/ httpp-proxy/utile/i
```

Comment: I tried this already before posting the question. the "npm ls i" is showing me the tree with no reference to 0.3.2

Comment: try upgrading json-proxy like "json-proxy":"*" and let me know if you still get the same error

Comment: Honestly nothing clever. I just went digging through npm docs and found what used it as a dependecy, updated it ,and good to go. Glad it worked